# What is the use of keyboard polling?

Tags: java, swing, events, awt

I am making a 2d graphics application using Java 1.6 .For receiving keyboard inputs ,i just use the `addKeyListener()` on the JPanel and in one of the callback methods keyPressed `(KeyEvent ke)` ,i do the drawing stuff

```
 `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
  {
        keyName=KeyEvent.getKeyText(ke.getKeyCode());
       /*calling other classes ,calculating values
        and drawing on the jpanel (moving an image ,etc)
        */
       ke.consume();
  }`
```

But there is another approach that i found in some blogs which goes something like this ,

1.)First initialize a `boolean[] keys=new boolean[256];`

2.)then, for each key event received ,just store the value into this boolean array.

```
`public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
{
            //storing the keyevent:true since its due to key being pressed
    keyMap[ke.getKeyCode()]=true;
    ke.consume();
}`


`public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke)
{
            //storing the keyevent:false since its due to key being released
    keyMap[ke.getKeyCode()]=false;
    ke.consume();
}`
```

finally there is method which loops through the boolean[] and checks the key state..

```
        `for(int i=0;i<keyMap.length;i++)
        {
            if(keyMap[i]==true)
            {

                           /* do some graphic tasks...*/
            }
        }`
```

whats the difference between the two patterns?

Comment: although the 2nd method produces code that looks more like how polling was done in the good old days it doesn't exactly looks like polling.  It's still a callback that modifies an array, not polling... And you have no choice about that in Java (at least not with 100% Java code).  If you want to go native you can really poll as long your keyboard is hooked to an USB port (if it's PS/2 it's IRQ/callback only as far as I remember).

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd approach allows you to have more than one keys pressed at the same time, usually to allow diagonal movement with double key presses.

Comment: Key handling is not going to be the bottleneck in your program.

Comment: addition to I82Much comment: unless you need to gain around 10^-9 millisecond speed, the first one might be faster as it does things as soon as the key get pressed.

Comment: But i think the keyevent is dispatched from different thread which might not sync well and so the second one might be better i guess

Comment: I believe Swing generally dispatches all events from the same thread.